# Single word for making more præcise

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I have, in some technical context, called some things x, but then discover that there are two classes of things falling under x, namely ys and zs.  I have præviously been talking about ys as xs simpliciter, but now I wish to make my term for those things more præcise and call them ys.  Is there a single word suitable for ‘making præcise’ in this context? Example of usage: ‘Let us … x (in)to(?) y.’

Comment: I don't think you need the diphthœngs.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you could provide a sentence with dots showing where the word should fit. @deadrat You mean ligatures, but I'm afraid yours is incorrect...I like them, though.

Comment: @Cerberus Doh! I stepped on my own punchline.  That's just pathetico-dynamic.  Yes, indeed, I meant *ligætures* or maybe  *ligætüres*.

Comment: @deadrat: Now you sound like a Metal band...

Comment: @deadrat: that's way too permissive. The diphthongs are plain wrong in all cases. Not even the New Yorker would put them there, that's how wrong they are.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Were you talking my ligatured comments as an endorsement for the OP's typography?

Comment: "make plain" (or "[explicate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/explicate)" for single word).

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything in particular that you don't like about **specify**?

Comment: Maybe specify is fine, but what I hoped for was something expressing more exactly the meaning of ‘making more præcise’, without expressing in addition that the result refers to a species.

Comment: FYI, this landed in the LQP queue.

Comment: @Nathaniel: The what?

Comment: Low-quality posts – someone flagged it as very low quality.  Someone probably felt it reads more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Oh, well, I don't care about that. I don't think this question warrants a longer answer (like many SWRs).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need:  ***to clarify***,

> to make (an idea, statement, etc.) clear or intelligible; to free from ambiguity.

From MerriamWebster

Answer (score 0):

I would use "differentiation," which Merriam-Webster defines as "development from the one to the many, the simple to the complex, or the homogeneous to the heterogeneous." In this case, you seem to be going from a single class to two distinct classes, the first category in M-W's definition. Possible synonyms would include contrasting, discernment, or discrimination.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think at least one of the answers already given (clarify) is perfectly clear, but I’ll nevertheless provide “[pinpoint](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pinpoint)” as an alternative that’s sometimes used together with “clarify,” especially in discussions of “clarifying words/terms” and/or “pinpointing [their] meanings.”

The following is an example of this joint use of “clarify” and “pinpoint” [with emphasis added along with my perhaps appropriate edits in brackets] found under the heading “6-Reclarified compounds” on page 14 of the discussion of Chinese [writing] characters in ‘[Reading and Writing Chinese](https://books.google.com/books?id=G8pX7AFFyPgC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22pinpoint+the+meaning%22+clarify&source=bl&ots=8TjSVUkB-h&sig=KFtdQAb9a7biTKkNktx4gsh_MEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj56ruBk63LAhVDWx4KHfMsBxUQ6AEIIjAB#v=snippet&q=%22the%20meaning%20of%20a%20character%20he%20was%20using%22%20%22because%20the%20word%20the%20character%20represented%20had%20a%20number%20of%20different%20meanings%22%20%22either%20to%20clarify%20the%20word%22%20%22pinpoint%20the%20meaning%20intended%20in%20the%20particular%20context.%E2%80%9D&f=false)’ by William McNaughton and Li Ying (accessed via ‘Google Books’):

> [In order] to better control the meaning of a character/[subpart] …
>   because the word/[idea] the character/[subpart] represented had a
>   number of different meanings (your case), [one] could add to the
>   existing character/[subpart] either to **clarify the word**/[idea] to
>   which it referred, or to **pinpoint the meaning** intended in the
>   particular context.

.

> **pinpoint**  tr.v[erb]. pinpointed, pinpointing, pinpoints
>   1. To locate or identify with **precision**: pinpointed the source of the problem.
>   2. To take **precise** aim at: pinpoint a target.

(first link to and definition of "pinpoint" from ‘American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition’, via ‘The Free Dictionary by Farlex’)